# Compression ring on angle valve under sink too loose

Tags: bathroom, valve

I was going to replace the valve and after finally getting the ring out using the tool. When I put the new one is just too loose, won't fit. If I compress it the valve just slides out. I bought a push-to-connect valve instead to have hot water but I wonder if the copper tube was too polished or if there is a different size. I am done with compression rings but also want to know if the push to connect would not leak. So far so good.

Ah and the tube was too short already to cut. The new valve nearly fit. Won't be easy to pull it out.

[image: new and old valve together]
Notice the ring of the new one slides in the cilinder and the old one doesn't even enters.

At the end use the push to connect and is working, no leaks so far[image: new valve]

I forgotten took pictures of the copper tube with the loose ring.

Comment: Are you certain you got the proper parts? What valve? What ring? How are you compressing it so the valve slides out? Copper pipes need to be nice and clean before soldering and should be before applying push-to-connect fittings, too. Yes, there are a variety of different sizes. It might help to [edit] in a picture of what you're trying to repair and the parts you're trying to use, including brand/model numbers for any and everything you can.

Comment: Added pictures. Yes they are standard under the sink valves as far as I can tell.

Comment: Those connections are not made to disassemble. You will have to cut the tube to remove.

Comment: The push to connect work and do not leak

Comment: I want to understand why the compression ring from the new valve, is bigger and won't make a seal in the pipe? Are they different sizes?

Comment: Because (if it's the right size at all) the compression ring you removed already compressed the pipe there slightly when it compressed into place umpity-seven years ago. Then you yanked that off and tried to put a new one in the same place. If you had just removed the nut and rings from the new valve and used the nut and rings already on the pipe, very likely would have worked fine.

Comment: I first did that. Kept the nut and ring from the old one. Celebrates victory but then, at night I saw a small drop below the nut. Searched that I needed to replaced the ring as they might have different profiles. But to my surprise it won't compress. So moved to push to compress. Maybe there is something to docfor the new ring to fit but PTC is working

Answer (score 2):

It's always a chancy thing to replace compression valves. Frequently the copper tubing is deformed, and there's not enough length to cut back to a good spot. Sometimes cheap valves just aren't to spec. Sometimes they need the strength of Atlas to tighten enough to stop leaking. Sometimes you get a valve that was returned to the store by some low-life customer with missing or damaged parts, such as a well-used compression ferrule.

Existing shutoff valves can usually be repaired, if not obviously damaged. Rubber bibb washers can easily be replaced. Entire stems and handles can be swapped with new ones if the same model is being sold somewhere.